# Setting a non-installed browser as default?

Tags: windows, windows-10, browser, file-association, protocol-handler

On my PC, I use the standalone version of Vivaldi (designed for use on USB Flash drives) on a separate disk to prevent bookmarks and settings from getting lost after a re-installation of Windows.

However, trying to set it as the default browser seems impossible. When using the Settings, I can only select browsers that were installed with an installer:

[image: Edge, Chrome and IE show up in the selection dialog, Vivaldi does not]

I'm getting a bit further using the Control Panel and "Set Associations". There, I was at least able to set vivaldi as the standard for `.htm` and `.html` files, but trying to do the same for `HTTP` and `HTTPS` protocol associations will again only show installed browsers.

[image: Successful associations for files]

[image: Only installed browsers showing up]

Is there a way to set an arbitrary `.exe` as the default for a protocol? Is there maybe another way to make Vivaldi my default browser without installing it traditionally?

Comment: *"...to prevent bookmarks and settings from getting lost after a re-installation of Windows."*  Just brainstorming, but don't we have options within both Chrome and Firefox to sync bookmarks/settings in the cloud automatically to avoid those type of problems?

Comment: agree with @Run5k Vivaldi should have an option to sync them, alternatively you can make a backup or just copy all bookmarks from the bookmark manager, before you reinstall. Also without a specific application (what I don't know of) it shouldn't be possible to do that. You can try going to chrome installation folder and replacing the files with your portable version, rename vivaldi.exe file to chrome.exe maybe it works

Comment: You can backup your bookmark file. Path of bookmark file for Vivaldi:: `C:\Users\usename\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\User data\Default\Bookmarks`

Comment: @downvoter: It would be helpful to tell me why you think this is a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Download [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/download/) setup .exe file. Open it with [7ZIP](http://www.7-zip.org/). Inside the installer (in screenshot *Vivaldi.1.11.917.39.exe*) there is another **vivaldi.7z** file, also open that. Extract the **Vivaldi-bin** folder from vivaldi.7z.

[image: Open_with_7zip]

- In that Vivaldi-bin folder, you find the main browser executable **vivaldi.exe**, open it. Here you get the standalone browser. You can copy the vivaldi-bin folder to any external drive.

[image: vivaldi_exe_file]

- Open **vivaldi://settings** in vivaldi.exe. Click on 'Set as default' button.

[image: vivaldi_deafult_setting]

- Now open Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Default Programs > Set Default Programs, click on Vivaldi and 'set this program as default' option. Now vivaldi is set as your default browser.

[image: Default_Vivaldi_controlPanel]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! By clicking "Set as Default", Vivaldi will also show up in the "Select default browser" prompt.

However, I don't think the first two bullet points of your answer are necessary in the context of this question (which assumes that the standalone version is already copied to a drive of some sort). Would you mind removing them? Or do you think that would take away from its value?

Comment: It's OK. I add the first two steps to show that I didn't install it as usual with installer but I use it as a standalone. And you also mentions that in your question.