# Apps not appearing in choice of default apps

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, vivaldi

I've got Windows 10 and have recently shifted my browser from Chrome to Vivaldi.

However, I cannot get Vivaldi to open email links - it always reverts to Chrome. I have tried looking in default programs, but Vivaldi does not appear as a choice, and it doesn't let me navigate to a program.

Does anyone know how to force a change in the default?

Thanks.

This is the same problem as this question:[Unable to set Brave browser as default browser in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1242081/unable-to-set-brave-browser-as-default-browser-in-windows-10)
But the answer provided there no longer works: it is no longer possible to navigate to

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Default Programs
```

in Windows 10. I just get a blank Control panel and the following directory: C:\Windows\System32\control.exe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to set Brave browser as default browser in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1242081/unable-to-set-brave-browser-as-default-browser-in-windows-10)

Comment: Thanks - same question, answer no longer working, at least for me. See edits.

Comment: What build of Windows 10?

Comment: Windows build 1803

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here, and it's a bit crazy: 
https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/26413/mailto-protocol/4

Also, don't muck about with the registry - I tried using [another answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1045349/where-windows-10-stores-default-email-app-in-its-registry), and didn't get anywhere. The answer below works perfectly.

The relevant part is:

> First, make sure custom handlers are allowed at
>   vivaldi://settings/handlers. [should be chrome://settings/handlers]
>
> Then, close Vivaldi.
>
> Use [JSONEdit](http://tomeko.net/software/JSONedit/), to edit
>   "C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\User
>   Data\Default\Preferences".
>
> Copy the following to the clipboard:
>
> ```
> {
>    "enabled" : true,
>    "ignored_protocol_handlers" : [],
>    "registered_protocol_handlers" : [
>       {
>          "default" : true,
>          "protocol" : "mailto",
>          "url" : "https://inbox.google.com/?mailto=%s"
>       }
>    ]
> }
> ```
>
> Right-click on the root node in the Preferences file in JSONEdit and
>   choose "Paste as child from clipboard". Then, rename the pasted object
>   to "custom_handlers" and save your changes. (This is assuming you
>   don't already have some custom handlers. If you do have some, you just
>   need to add to the registered_protocol_handlers array.
>
> In Vivaldi, go to vivaldi://settings/handlers [should be chrome://settings/handlers], click the 3 dots to the
>   right of the inbox.google.com entry (that's now there) and choose "set
>   as default". Then you can go into Default Apps in Windows and set
>   Vivaldi as the default mail client. Then you should be good to go.
>
> On a side, for Gmail (mail.google.com), it's:
>
> navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto",
>   "https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s",
>   "mail.google.com");

Answer (score 0):

> However, I cannot get Vivaldi to open email links - it always reverts to Chrome. I have tried looking in default programs, but Vivaldi does not appear as a choice, and it doesn't let me navigate to a program.

I didn't have any problems setting the default browser to **Vivaldi**.

1) Install **Vivaldi**

2) Open **Vivaldi**

3) Click **Settings** from within **Vivaldi**

[image]

4) Click **Set as Default**

[image]

5) From within the **Settings** UWP application click on the current default program under **Web Browser**.

[image]

6) Select **Vivaldi**.

[image]
[image]

7)   If **Vivaldi** is not listed select set the default program by file extension instead.

[image]

Comment: If **Vivaldi** isn't listed then you should uninstall it and reinstall it.  It wasn't installed in my VM, I installed it, doing these steps set the default browser when I click a link within an application.  You also should change any setting, set to use Chrome, to use **Vivaldi** instead ovbiously.

Comment: Thanks - default browser is all good, just not email - my problem is it won't show in the choice of programs. Will try reinstalling.

Comment: Have posted the solution. Your answer deals with the browser default, but not the mailto default, which is what my problem was.